# Newest version of luatexja interferes with vertical alignment of text

Tags: luatex, vertical-alignment, tex-core, luatexja

Today when I was compiling a document, I found that the header was mis-aligned. After a bit debugging, it seems to be the package `luatexja` (version 20220807) that is causing the problem. Below is a MWE that essentially reproduce this behavior.

```
\documentclass{book}

% \usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode
\llap{\thepage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.833\textwidth}
  Test
\end{minipage}

\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.833\textwidth}
  \hfill Test
\end{minipage}
\rlap{\thepage}

\end{document}
```

Without `luatexja`:

[image]

With `luatexja`:

[image]

---

**Update:** This has been fixed in version 20220810.

Comment: it is quite easy to open a ticket there. You can even do it without an account.

Comment: I see that you opened a ticket and a fix is on the way to ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the indication yesterday and the above comment :)